# Get ASP.NET Repeater to display only the 3 newest entries from a SQL Server datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I could not find an answer for my question but I think you can help me :)

I have a repeater in an ASP.NET website that I want to only show the 3 newest entries. I know it's possible but I can't get it to work.. :(

My repeater looks like this

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="Sql_letter">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <p><%# Eval("Wishlist_Letter_FirstName") %> fra <%# Eval("Wishlist_Letter_City") %></p>

        <p>Har skrevet til Julemanden</p>

        <asp:TextBox ID="r" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Wishlist_Letter_Message")%>' TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="txt_message" BackColor="Transparent" BorderWidth="0" BorderStyle="None" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>

        <br /> <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And my `SqlDataSource`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Sql_letter" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:sqlconnection %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Wishlist_Letter]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: What is "newest"? Do you have a timestamp field? There is no (guaranteed) ordering on your data source.

Comment: My Table has ID's and i want it to show the 3 or 5 newest ID's :) With that i mean i want the ID 9,10,11 to show insted of 1,2,3 :)

Comment: You can change Select TOP 3 * FROM [Wishlist_Letter] order by 1 desc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SelectCommand` should be something like

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM [Wishlist_Letter] ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC
```

but you need to have a `Timestamp` field or something equal on your table. There is no natural ordering on ms sql which guarantees to return the latest three entries.

In your case it should be

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM [Wishlist_Letter] ORDER BY [ID] DESC
```

Answer (score 5):

Could you not change your select command to something like

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM [Wishlist_Letter] ORDER BY EntryDate DESC
```

Where `EntryDate` in the above query would be the definitive field to indicate if it would be in the top 3?